# Runnig a block of bootstrap 5 code in special Conditions

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I would like to run this code when the window width is 500 px or more and Run the other code block when the width is 499 px or less . How can I do this

500 px or more :

```
<div class="card text-center d-inline-block m-2" style="width: 13rem;" >
   <img src=".." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
   <div class="card-body">
       <h5 class="card-title" style="font-size: 1rem;">name</h5>
       <p class="card-text text-muted" style="font-size: 0.8rem;">100 $</p>
       <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" style="font-size: 0.9rem;">watch</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

499 or less :

```
<div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 540px;">
     <div class="row g-0">
<div class="col-md-4">
  <img src="..." class="img-fluid rounded-start" alt="...">
</div>
<div class="col-md-8">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
    <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to include both of them inside a `div` each, which would be conditionally rendered according to viewport size.
For the `div` with <= 499px, you'll need to enclose the whole part in:

```
<div class="d-md-none">
</div>
```

And for the `div` with >=500px, you'll need to enclose the whole part in:

```
<div class="d-none d-md-block">
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deathstalkersid/tvLp6d1k/1/)